# trackEvent show up where in GA?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have this code, the code runs without exceptions.

```
(function () {
    $("a.ga-track").click(function () {
        var anchor = this;
        try {
            _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "External links", anchor.hostname]);
        } catch (err) { }

        setTimeout(function () {
            document.location.href = anchor.href;
        }, 100);
        return false;
    });
})();
```

Were in GA should I find the statistics that this generate?

edit: This is the site
http://andersmalmgren.github.io/FreePIE/

updated my code to this as `target="_blank"` do not need timeout

```
(function () {
    $("a.ga-track").click(function () {
        var anchor = this;
        try {
            _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "External links", anchor.href]);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if ($(this).attr("target") !== "_blank") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.location.href = anchor.href;
            }, 100);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it would work it would show up in the content reports section under the menu label "Events". Since you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code on your site and **[edited to delete  wrong information]** won't show up at all.

In response to the comment: In the site you are using the following analytics integration:

```
<!--[if !IE]><script>fixScale(document);</script><![endif]-->       
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-36162327-1");
            pageTracker._trackPageview();
        } catch (err) { }
    </script>
```

That is deprecated synchronous syntay. The asynchronous ga.push syntax will not work with this code. The example in your link refers to the asynchronous version of the Google code.

Comment: Its based on this code example https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Comment: @Anders I expanded my answer to explain the problem a little better.

Comment: aha, didnt know it was updated (No wanring or anything in GA GUI), will update the API and test, thanks

Comment: Actually right now Google rolls out yet another version (universal analytics) which is compatible neither with the synchronous nor  the asynchronous trackingcode. Universal Analytics is offered as default when you create a new account or property. Asynchronous tracking is still avaiable and AFAIK allows you to continue with an existing account, so at the moment this might be the better choice for you.

Comment: Works now, after API update, the part you talked about earlier with wrong arguments does not hold however. Thanks for the help!